# Smack shows online/offline status incorrectly

Tags: openfire, smack

This is my code to show online of line of friends of the current user.

```
        final String me = "hieugioi@xxx.xxx.x.xx";
        connection.connect();
        connection.login(me, "123456");
        final Roster roster = connection.getRoster();

    final Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
    for(final RosterEntry entry : entries) {
        System.out.println("User: " + entry.getUser());
        System.out.println("Name: " + entry.getName());
        //System.out.println("Status: " + entry.getStatus());


        final Presence p = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
        System.out.println("====== Mode: " + p.getMode());
        System.out.println("====== Status: " + p.getStatus());
    }
```

The log shows

```
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): User: hieungoan@xxx.xxx.x.xx
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): Name: hieungoan
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): ====== Mode: null
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): ====== Status: null
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): User: hieutot@xxx.xxx.x.xx
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): Name: hieutot
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): ====== Mode: null
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): ====== Status: null
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): User: hieuhay@xxx.xxx.x.xx
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): Name: hieuhay
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): ====== Mode: null
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): ====== Status: null
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): User: hieukhoe@xxx.xxx.x.xx
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): Name: hieukhoe
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): ====== Mode: null
12-24 09:37:18.029: I/System.out(2831): ====== Status: null
```

In fact the users `hieutot` and `hieungoan` is **online** in Openfire but it always show NULL as above! What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the section on [**Listening for Roster and Presence Changes**](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/roster.html).